# jQuery plugin and angular repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Given a jQuery plugin, what is the cleanest way to initialise it on a list of elements rendered by `ng-repeat`?

For example, i want to make a list of words draggable. In the controller i take the list from the API:

```
$scope.words = Words.get(...)
```

And in the view i iterate on them:

```
<article ng-controller="WordsCtrl">
    <div class="word" ng-repeat="word in words">
        {{word}}
    </div>
</article>
```

What is left is to run the plugin initialisation code, like in:

```
$(elem).children('.word').draggable()
```

But this needs to be run after every change in the scope. Where does this go?

Comment: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can create a simple `jqDraggable` directive that will call `.draggable()`:

```
app.directive('jqDraggable', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, elm, attr) {
          elm.draggable();
      }
  };       
});
```

You would then do:

```
<article ng-controller="WordsCtrl">
    <div jq-draggable="true" class="word" ng-repeat="word in words">
        {{word}}
    </div>
</article>
```

This should also work when your `$scope.words` changes.

Here is a sample plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ywWifeNPcTFYTYFMI2Of?p=preview

Comment: If i get it right, your solution here is to put the directive on the same line of `ng-repeat`, instead of trying on the children as i was. Pretty elegant.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is create a directive on the parent element that house the repeated items.  You then create a $watch expression that watches the scope of the ng-repeat and if it changes you apply .draggable on it's children.

here's a plugin already done for you

http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

to answer your question about watching the scope though here's a roughe example:

your element would look like:

```
<div draggable="items">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
</div>

app.directive('draggable',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,$elem,$attrs){
        $scope.$watch($attrs.draggable,function(nv,ov) {
         //the scope of repeat has changed do something here
        }
    }
}
});
```

so it will sit there and watch items and you can apply draggable when it changes

Comment: what is the `draggable="items"` and `$attrs.draggable` necessary for? also, should i then run `nv.forEach(function(e) { $(e).draggable(); }`?